# updatepanel asynpostbacktrigger does not throw defined event?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, triggers, updatepanel, postback

I have the following code.

What i want is when the ddlProvince dropdown is changed, to throw the event SelectedIndexChanged, however that method is never accessed.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlCountries" runat="server">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlProvince" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
<tr>
    <td><asp:Literal ID="Literal37" Text="<%$Resources:glossary,country %>" runat="server"/></td>
    <td>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountries" CssClass="textbox" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<cc1:cascadingdropdown ID="cddCountries" runat="server" Category="Country" Enabled="True" LoadingText="<%$Resources:Glossary,loading %>" PromptText="<%$Resources:Glossary,country_choose %>" 
ServiceMethod="GetCountries" TargetControlID="ddlCountries">
</cc1:cascadingdropdown>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="errortext" Text="<%$Resources:Glossary,required %>" SetFocusOnError="true" ID="rfvcboScenario" runat="server" InitialValue="" ControlToValidate="ddlCountries" Display="Dynamic" />


    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong><asp:Literal ID="Literal9" Text="<%$Resources:Glossary,province %>" runat="server" /> *</strong></td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProvince" CssClass="textbox" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>       
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="errortext" Text="<%$Resources:Glossary,required %>" SetFocusOnError="true" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" InitialValue="" ControlToValidate="ddlProvince" Display="Dynamic" />
    <cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="cddProvince" runat="server" TargetControlID="ddlProvince" ParentControlID="ddlCountries"   
        Category="Province" LoadingText="<%$Resources:Glossary,loading %>" prompttext="<%$Resources:Glossary,province_select %>" ServiceMethod="GetProvincesForCountry" >
    </cc1:CascadingDropDown>


</td>
</tr>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Currently this codeline is never hit:

```
Protected Sub ddlProvince_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlProvince.SelectedIndexChanged
    ReportError("ddlProvince_SelectedIndexChanged", "")
End Sub
```

update:
previously I had the Autopostback="true" attribute on the ddlProvince control, however, that caused a full postback (issue also described here: [Drop Down List (in Update Panel) causing FULL PostBack!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138565/drop-down-list-in-update-panel-causing-full-postback))

What am I missing?

Comment: Probably you found it already- you need to set `AutoPostback="true"` of ddlProvince,  then the AsyncPostBack works fine. You need to keep the AsyncPostBackTrigger as well.

Comment: This should be your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
 You need to set `AutoPostBack="true"` for the dropdownlist. Change this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProvince" CssClass="textbox" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

to this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProvince" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" >
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: I thought so too, but then I experienced this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138565/drop-down-list-in-update-panel-causing-full-postback

Comment: Isn't the event already attached via this line:
Protected Sub ddlProvince_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlProvince.SelectedIndexChanged
I also tried doing it your way and removed the 'Handles' part but still no luck...

Comment: thank youuuuuuuu i have started with auto post back but it acted wired but your post made try again and i understood what i did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you haven't set the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event in the Markup as seen above.

Three properties you should set: `OnSelectedIndexChanged`, `AutoPostback` & `EnableViewState`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProvince" runat="server" 
     AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true"
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProvince_SelectedIndexChanged">                
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Incase you are binding your dropdownlist in `page_Load` event, place it inside `!IsPostback` condition check:

```
protected void page_Load ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {
            //DropDownList data bind and all...
      }
}
```